# Outlook 2016 only syncs folders when clicked

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016 with Exchange v15.1. If I log into Outlook Web Access (OWA) I can see dozens of unread email throughout my folders, but in Outlook I have to click each folder individually to get it to synchronize.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) *I have to click each folder individually*...do you literally "select" the folder and it immediately syncs? Or are you completing any other steps? 2) Does Outlook claim "ALL FOLDERS ARE UP TO DATE" in the status bar when you know they aren't? 3) Do you have any view settings that might be hiding unread messages?

Comment: Yeah, I click the folder and then will get the notification in the tray `updating FolderA`. I haven't checked for an overall message, and I have no view settings hiding unread email - I can see them fine once they're synced. Also, I know they're only just now syncing, because I can see the progress bar... progressing. :)

Comment: What do you know about your Exchange server?  Is this Office 365, your organization, or something else?  e.g. do you know the version of Exchange?

Comment: It's exchange, looks like `15.1.x.x`

Comment: Also, in Outlook > File > Info > Account Settings > *E-Mail* tab, double-click your Exchange account and tell me if "Use Cached Exchange Mode" is checked or not, and if so, what the "Mail to keep offline" slider is set to.

Comment: Yes, it's checked - set to `12 months`

Comment: Are you using any Public or Shared folders of any type, or have our Outlook profile connected to any other users' mailboxes?

Comment: Nope, I do not.

Comment: Try creating a new Outlook profile against this Exchange account and see if the issue persists.  Also, since this is Exchange 2016 which is still in Preview, there's ample room for this actually being a bug.

Comment: @Twisty - for now, this seems to have done the trick. Add an official answer for your bounty, if you wish.

Comment: Answer added. Glad this got things sorted out for you.

Comment: I have the same problem while using my web domain with my email server. The emails in the inbox will not sync until I click on some other folder and get back. I use IMAP protocol but the problem is still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new Outlook profile for this Exchange account. Sometimes odd behavior in Outlook can be sorted out with a new profile.

Also, since Exchange 2016 is still in Preview, there's the possibility this is due to a bug, although I searched diligently for reports by others of similar behavior and found none.