# Why does Outlook 2016 only check and receive message on one email account when that account is selected?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have Outlook 2016 (business subscription) with two email accounts; one is Exchange, the other is IMAP/SMTP.

- The Exchange one works as expected: I receive emails any time I'm online and Outlook is running.
- **The IMAP/SMTP one, however, seems to only check for new emails when that specific account's inbox is selected.**

I didn't deliberately set it to do this, and I've been through all the settings I can think of to check.

I have the same email account on my phone (Android Mail app) and I get push notifications reliably, so the email account is clearly capable of this. This is the full version of Outlook 2016, not the preview, and I've tried recreating the account and it still has the same problem, so this [isn't a duplicate of this similar-looking question](https://superuser.com/questions/943442/outlook-2016-only-syncs-folders-when-clicked).

What could make Outlook do this? How can I make Outlook update the IMAP/SMTP account regardless of what view I've selected, same as the Exchange account?

Comment: SMTP is associated only with outbound mail, perhaps you meant POP3 or IMAP?

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I meant IMAP. Will edit.